# How can I connect to ray in docker on Mac M1?

Tags: python, docker, apple-m1, ray

The post is long mainly because of all the error messages. The gist is:

1. I start a docker container with ray(latest tag has ray version 1.9.2 at the moment)
2. using `docker exec` I start a python process within this container
3. From python I try to connect to ray
4. The attempt to connect fails on M1 Mac while works on Linux

```sh
➜ docker run -it rayproject/ray:latest
$ ray start --head --block --num-gpus=1
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
(base) ray@8346ae81903e:~$ ray start --head --dashboard-host 0.0.0.0 --block --include-dashboard trueLocal node IP: 172.17.0.2
2022-01-27 01:22:01,109 INFO services.py:1340 -- View the Ray dashboard at http://172.17.0.2:8265
2022-01-27 01:22:01,119 WARNING services.py:1826 -- WARNING: The object store is using /tmp instead of /dev/shm because /dev/shm has only 67108864 bytes available. This will harm performance! You may be able to free up space by deleting files in /dev/shm. If you are inside a Docker container, you can increase /dev/shm size by passing '--shm-size=1.78gb' to 'docker run' (or add it to the run_options list in a Ray cluster config). Make sure to set this to more than 30% of available RAM.
[mutex.cc : 926] RAW: pthread_getschedparam failed: 1

--------------------
Ray runtime started.
--------------------

Next steps
  To connect to this Ray runtime from another node, run
    ray start --address='172.17.0.2:6379' --redis-password='XXXXX'
  
  Alternatively, use the following Python code:
    import ray
    ray.init(address='auto', _redis_password='XXXXX')
  
  To connect to this Ray runtime from outside of the cluster, for example to
  connect to a remote cluster from your laptop directly, use the following
  Python code:
    import ray
    ray.init(address='ray://<head_node_ip_address>:10001')

...
```

Then I use `docker exec -it ... bash` to connect to the container, run `python` repl and try using the commands suggested by the previous ray output.

```py
import ray
ray.init(address='auto', _redis_password='XXXXX')
```

Results in

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py", line 105, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 834, in init
> redis_address, _, _ = services.validate_redis_address(address)
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/_private/services.py", line 375, in validate_redis_address
> address = find_redis_address_or_die()
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/_private/services.py", line 287, in find_redis_address_or_die
> "Could not find any running Ray instance. "
> ConnectionError: Could not find any running Ray instance. Please specify the one to connect to by setting `address`.

Attempt to connect by specific address don't end well either.

```py
ray.init(address='ray://localhost:10001')
```

> [mutex.cc : 926] RAW: pthread_getschedparam failed: 1
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py", line 105, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 775, in init
> return builder.connect()
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/client_builder.py", line 155, in connect
> ray_init_kwargs=self._remote_init_kwargs)
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/client_connect.py", line 42, in connect
> ray_init_kwargs=ray_init_kwargs)
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/client/**init**.py", line 228, in connect
> conn = self.get_context().connect(*args, **kw_args)
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/client/**init**.py", line 88, in connect
> self.client_worker._server_init(job_config, ray_init_kwargs)
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/client/worker.py", line 698, in _server_init
> f"Initialization failure from server:\n{response.msg}")
> ConnectionAbortedError: Initialization failure from server:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/client/server/proxier.py", line 629, in Datapath
> "Starting Ray client server failed. See "
> RuntimeError: Starting Ray client server failed. See ray_client_server_23000.err for detailed logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and resolved this issue by setting `dashboard_host` to `0.0.0.0`.

```
ray.init(dashboard_host="0.0.0.0",dashboard_port=6379)
```

Comment: No idea how, but it works :) Thanks!